# Обновить TextView после закрытия alerdDialog

Tags: java, android

В каком направлении копать? Есть активити, при нажатии на кнопку вызывается `alerdDialog` в котором выходит список (массив) цифр, при выборе меняется переменная, но не обновляется `textView` элемент, после закрытия диалога (но переменная меняется). И меняет своё значение при повторном вызове диалога

```
public class HlamActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView helpMyTextView;
Auxiliary auxiliary;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hlam);

helpMyTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
button= (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonHlam);

helpMyTextView.setText("Значение = "+MainActivity.Q_Q);



button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {

    start();

 } });

}
public void start(){
    auxiliary.alerdDialogQ(this);

}
```

др. *.java

```
public class Auxiliary {
Context context;
public void alerdDialogQ(Context context){
    res = context.getResources();
    final String [] Q = {"10","20","30","40","50"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle(res.getString(R.string.numberQ));
    builder.setItems(Q, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

      MainActivity.Q_Q = Integer.parseInt(Q[i]);

           //????
        }
    });
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.create();
    builder.show();

}}
```

Найденные варианты:

1) использовать класс Handler

2) Создать таймер, и обновлять класс каждые 200 мс

3) Перидовать данные через Integer

Comment: Попробуйте обновлять данные TextView в onResume активности. Я  вообще не вижу у вас, где обновляется TextView, кроме как при создании активности в onCreate.

Comment: Либо сделайте вот так https://habr.com/post/259805/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае правильно будет использовать интерфейс и передавать через него сигнал в активность, где будут проходить все изменения.

например вот так:

```
public class Auxiliary {
Context context;
DialogCallback callback;

    interface DialogCallback {
        void dialogCallback(int data);
    }

    public void alerdDialogQ(Context context){
        callback = (DialogCallback) context;
        ...
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                callback.(Integer.parseInt(Q[i]));
            }
        ...
    }
}
```

А в активности прописать:

```
public class HlamActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Auxiliary.DialogCallback {

@Override
void dialogCallback(int data){
    Q_Q = data;
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(data));
}
```

Статическую переменную `MainActivity.Q_Q`  вашем случае использовать не рекомендуется.

Comment: callback = (DialogCallback) context;

Ошибка, что то связанное с Handler.handleCallback

Comment: вы `implements` в нужной активности прописали? скиньте название ошибки из стектрейса?

Comment: Да ты прав, я не правильно implements прописал
Код рабочий, работает как часы, спасибо!